# sql if statement in store procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

For some reason MYSQL will not let me create this procedure, can anybody see what the problem is?

It works if I remove the IF statement but to me the if statement looks ok.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure add_new_room(IN buildingID INT,
              IN inName TEXT,
                              IN inWeeks INT,
                              IN inAnnual TEXT,
                              IN inWeekly TEXT)
BEGIN
DECLARE roomnameid INT;
DECLARE roomcount INT;

SELECT count(roomID) from tblRooms WHERE roomName = inName into roomcount;

if roomcount = 1 then

    SELECT roomID from tblRooms 
       WHERE roomName = inName into roomnameid;

    INSERT INTO tblAccommRoom 
      (roomWeeks,roomID,accommodationID,roomWeeklyRent, roomAnnualRent) 
    VALUES (inWeeks,roomnameid,buildingID,inWeekly, inAnnual);

else

    INSERT INTO tblRooms (roomName) VALUES inName;

    INSERT INTO tblAccommRoom 
     (roomWeeks, roomID, accommodationID, roomWeeklyRent, roomAnnualRent) 
    VALUES (inWeeks,LAST_INSERT_ID(),buildingID,inWeekly, inAnnual);

end if;

END
```

Comment: Do you need a "Begin" and "End" around the guts of your if statement?

Comment: Is a compilation error, or execution error

Comment: i've got a begin and and end

Comment: not sure which error, it just freezes and says "loading"

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `CASE WHEN` statement instead of the `IF` statement, which allows the code to work a little more universally with MS SQL and MySQL.

```
CASE WHEN roomcount = 1 THEN...ELSE...END
```

I don't do a lot of work with MySQL, but I also typically see `IF` statements contained within parentheses and commas utilized rather than spelling out `THEN` and `ELSE`.

```
IF(condition,then statement,else statement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the SELECT to this:

```
SELECT count(roomID) into roomcount from tblRooms WHERE roomName = inName;
```

then, you should be able to use 'roomcount' later on.